# org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)

Tags: spring, ejb, weblogic

Environment: Weblogic, Spring, Hibernate and EJB

Code:

```
public class ServiceImpl    
{        
    @Transactional  
    public void test()  
    {                   
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();                 
    }   
}   

public class WebLayerClass  
{           
    service.test(); 
}
```

When I run it, I get UnexpectedRollbackException instead of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
"org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction already rolled back (probably due to a timeout)"
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?  Is it bubbling up your ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and being caught by UnexpectedRollbackException ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.
Web layer makes call to EJB -> Spring -> DAO, transaction is getting rolled back if any exception occurs in spring layer. This is the desired behavior and working fine. 
Based on the exception i handle differently in weblayer. when i put a catch in web layer i get UnexpectedRollbackException instead of the actual exception.

Comment: We have upgraded hibernate 3.x to 4.x. When working with hibernate 3.x all fine.

3.x configuration

<prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor">de.unicreditgroup.esa.persistence.hibernate.EsaChangeInterceptor</prop>
<prop key="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.ejb.transaction.JoinableCMTTransactionFactory</prop>

Comment: 4.x configuration
<prop key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor">de.unicreditgroup.esa.persistence.hibernate.EsaChangeInterceptor</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>
Is any configuration with transaction incorrect ?

Comment: I couldn't add complete log here, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342759/hibernate-and-spring-upgradation   

Thank  you